# Powershell: removing duplicates removes all data

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I'm developing a piece of code that searches for an array of users and pulls their AD groups, sorts them, and removes the duplicates. When I run it however, I only end up with Domain Users... which is most certainly incorrect.

```
$myUsers = "test1","test2","test3"
$test = @(foreach ($element in $myUsers) {
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $element | select name
}) | sort -Unique
write-output $test
```

This is the output I receive:

```
name        
----        
Domain Users
```

Where is the code going wrong? If I remove | sort -Unique then I get a 140 long list of AD groups so I know Get-ADprincipalGroupMembership is pulling them correctly...

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide what to apply the unique switch on.

```
$test = @(foreach ($element in $myUsers) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $element | select Name
  }) | sort -Unique Name
```

By adding name to the sort, you will get what you are looking for, a list of unique groups that all the users are collectively part of.

Comment: This worked. I was going insane trying to figure out the issue. Thanks!